# Function is inaccessible 

Tags: c++

I have

```
// file BoardInitializer.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class BoardInitializer
{
    static int *beginBoard;
    static int *testBoard;
    static void testBoardInitialize();
}



// file mh.cpp
#include "BoardInitializer.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BoardInitializer.testBoardInitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

and I implemented `BoardInitializer::testBoardInitialize` in `mh.cpp`. 
But I get the error "Function is inaccessible". What's wrong?

Comment: when I write "    public static void testBoardInitialize();" it gave me an error expected :

Comment: sorry. very sorry. I forgot ":"

Comment: thanks for help. should I delete this post?

Comment: @Masoud No. You should accept an answer.

Comment: Thats up to you, but personally I think there are some answers mentioning additonal aspects. Sometimes you get answers answering more then you have asked for ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default protection level for a `class` in C++ is `private` (with
the others being `public` and `protected`). That means all your
members and your member function are private and only accessible by
other member functions of that class or friends (functions or classes)
of that class.

The function main is neither and you end up with the error.

C++ provides a handy shortcut (or C legacy cruft, depending on your
worldview) called `struct`, where the default protection level is
`public`.

```
class my_class {
public:
  int my_int;      
};
```

or

```
struct my_struct {
  int my_int;
};
```

should show the difference.

Answer (score 9):

Classes have implicit `private` access, you need to add an explicit `public:` statement before your method. Additionally its a static method and needs to be addressed using the `::` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Class elements are private by default. Write this:

```
class BoardInitializer
{
public:
    static int *beginBoard;
    static int *testBoard;
    static void testBoardInitialize();
};
```

Struct elements are public by default. Write this:

```
struct BoardInitializer
{
    static int *beginBoard;
    static int *testBoard;
    static void testBoardInitialize();
};
```

Static class elements must be accessed with `::` operator.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to make the function public by adding `public:` at the start of your class definition.

Answer (score 3):

Class properties are private by default. You have to add public: to your class.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by everyone, class members are by default `private`.
If you want to make it accessible, just make them `public`.

If you still want to protect/abstract/hide your data members(here `*beginBoard` and `testBoard`) just make the function `public` like:

```
class BoardInitializer {
    static int *beginBoard;
    static int *testBoard;
 public:
   static void testBoardInitialize();
}
```

Comment: You can format whole blocks of code by indenting them with 4 spaces (as opposed to using backticks, which are better for single line code snippets). There are more details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (for those who come here in the future) is that you forgot the `public` keyword when inheriting. That is, you should have `class Base: public Derived`.